# Parsing xml multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application I have to parsed xml file two times in a single build as per my applications requirement.But I am loading the array in only first parse . So is there any effect on my application performance due to parsing xml twice?

Comment: better is to load first time (if it will not change), and save that locally, and use the saved version.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you are using dom-parser or sax-parse :-

1. sax is an event based parser while dom is not
2. sax is forward only where as dom can be accessed both ways.
3. sax parses the file as it reads where as dom loads into memory to parse
4. Sax does not have memory constraints where as the dom 
   has momory constraints as xml file is loaded into the 
   momory to parse the file.
5. sax is read only , dom is read and write both.

So , if you have a very large xml and you are using dom the yes it has implications on performance of application.Sax is advisable on mobile platforms (anyways parsing 2 times does reduce the applicaion's performance but if you have 2 parse 2 times you may use dom as it retains it's node and you need not parse 2 times.)

For very small xml's , both are almost same.